# What is the difference between the Firefox "Bookmarks Toolbar" and the "Bookmarks Menu"

Tags: firefox, bookmarks

I am trying to clean up my bookmarks and I want to know:

**What is the difference between the Firefox "Bookmarks Toolbar" and the "Bookmarks Menu"**

- Where are each of these in Firefox
- What determines if a bookmark is "Unorganised"?

Comment: I don't suppose you have tried [Google](https://www.google.com)? [This](http://forums.mozillazine.org/viewtopic.php?f=38&t=1658115) was found via a simple Google search.

Answer (score 2):

The bookmarks menu is the menu you get when you click the (right half) of the bookmarks button. The bookmarks toolbar is an optional toolbar that can be displayed below the address bar. Unorganized bookmarks (usually called Unsorted Bookmarks) are those that are not in either the bookmarks menu or the bookmarks toolbar. Bookmarks start out Unsorted, and you must choose whether they go in the menu or the toolbar.

Items in the Bookmarks Toolbar are also available as a submenu of the Bookmarks Menu, as are Unsorted Bookmarks.